# Some Numpy reshape questions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, shapes

I am trying to learn how to reshape correctly, so any help will be welcome.

```
o = np.arange(2910140).reshape(2270, 1282)
o.shape
(2270, 1282)
x = np.arange(2270).reshape(2270)
x.shape
(2270,)
```

How can I reshape "x" to have the same number of columns than "o"?

```
x.reshape(-1, 1282)
```

fail with the following error:

```
    x.reshape(-1, 1282)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2270 into shape (1282)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried this too:

```
x.reshape(2910140, 1282)
```

Error:

```
    x.reshape(2910140, 1282)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2270 into shape (2910140,1282)
```

Doesn't the value "-1" indicate numpy to calculate it by itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Numpy does not allow ragged arrays. Since 1282 doesn't divide 2270 evenly, you will be left with empty values in the last row.

Comment: You're trying to to shape a 2270 element long list into a 1282 element long list...

Comment: For broadcasting purposes, `x[:,None]` or `x.reshape(2270,1)`